# image, then align text to right

Tags: html, css

At this moment, I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="6" />
    <a href="1.html" title="1" id="ton">Hendrerit</a>
    <a href="2.html" title="2" id="ton">Phasellus</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu a#ton:link,
.menu a#ton:visited,
.menu a#ton:active {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 19px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/BT5K9/

Which is the best way to align links to right? I want only for modern browsers, so I guess it's something simple. `text-align` don't work in my case because of the `display: inline-block`, I guess. Maybe without float? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you selecting the pseudo-classes? Better apply a class instead of an ID to the links and use this. Then you just select `#menu .link-class` as the selector. Other than that, try wrapping the links in a div and apply `text-align` to this.

Comment: do you want them aligned one under the other on the side of the image? or as they are but vertically aligned to the middle of the image?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BT5K9/1/

Comment: You are using class selector for menu div and in your css i can see you are using ID selector for menu.

Comment: @VikasGhodke To be precisely: He is using a class in his HTML and is trying to select it with an ID.

Comment: Why don't you want to use float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not against using `span` or `float`,
here's a solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BT5K9/2/)

Comment: If you want the text to align with the right side of the browser, yes `float` is the only solution. That's what it's made for. Also, you don't need to specify the `:link`, `:active`, and `:visited`. Here's a simpler, equivalent code: http://jsfiddle.net/BT5K9/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to use float:

```
.menu img
{
display: block;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
}

.menu a
{
text-align: right; 
display:block;  
}
```

[here is jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/BT5K9/8/)

Comment: Good suggestion. The only issue is that this approach forces each new link to appear on a new line.